# How to read row wise details in excel file using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to read a excel file of .xls format from external storage. Using file picker i have got its path. But now the problem is i have to read the excel file row wise and save it in an array.

I could not find any library like poi similar to java.

The expected result should be like Workbook=>sheet1=>row(i)

Answer (score 1):

```
 OutlinedButton(
              
        onPressed: ()  async {

           ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/mydata.xlsx");
           
        _upload(data);
        
     }
)


static Future<void> _upload(var data) async {

 var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
    
     List<dynamic> excelList = [];
     


  for (var table in excel.tables.keys) 
     {

      for(int rowIndex= 1 ;rowIndex <=excel.tables[table].maxRows; rowIndex++) 
      {
      
       Sheet sheetObject = excel['Sheet1'];
         
      var excelfileDetails = new MyExcelTable();

      excelfileDetails.name = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex:0,rowIndex: rowIndex)).value.toString(); 
      excelfileDetails.age = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex:1,rowIndex: rowIndex)).value; 
      excelfileDetails.state = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex:2,rowIndex: rowIndex)).value.toString(); 
      excelfileDetails.country = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex:3,rowIndex: rowIndex)).value.toString(); 
      excelfileDetails.occupation = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex:4,rowIndex: rowIndex)).value.toString();  
     
      excelList.add(excelfileDetails);
     
     
    }
  }  
}


    class MyExcelTable
    {
         var name;

         var age;

         var state;

        var country;

        var occupation;
  

    MyExcelTable({this.name, this.age, this.state, this.country, this.occupation});

}
```

Comment: `Excel` object comes from where?

Comment: You have to import 'package:excel/excel.dart'  to use Excel. then you create an object of it to do your manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an Excel file or could you also save it as .csv data? If you can save it as .csv, you can simply read it as a normal Text.

Comment: It is only a excel file.

Answer (score 0):

have a try : https://pub.dev/packages/spreadsheet_decoder

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:spreadsheet_decoder/spreadsheet_decoder.dart';

main() {
  var bytes = new File.fromUri(fullUri).readAsBytesSync();
  var decoder = new SpreadsheetDecoder.decodeBytes(bytes);
  var table = decoder.tables['Sheet1'];
  var values = table.rows[0];
  ...
  decoder.updateCell('Sheet1', 0, 0, 1337);
  new File(join(fullUri).writeAsBytesSync(decoder.encode());
  ...
}
```